# AngularJS elements located in components are fired only after the second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have AngularJS (1.x) component - or actually directive to be precise, 
and the elements inside this directive are get fired/worked/actioned only in the second click.

For example: a dropdown will not toggle unless you click twice.
After the second click the toggle will be on each next click.

It's like the elements are not digested in the DOM.

This is the component call:

```
<dropdown-custom-component-example></dropdown-custom-component-example>
```

This is the component html file:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn pl-2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-options"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".create-supplier">
      <i class="fa icon-plus text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Action
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your onclick function code.

Comment: @MerajKhan bootstraps dropdown don't need an onclick function to toggle.

Comment: @J. Sadi on double click I ask.

Comment: The onclick is in the boostrap css file probably. But this is not always require two clicks - only at the first time it like ignores the first click, then on the second, third, fourth and so for and so on, it opens the dropdown once.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to digest by your own inside your directive, after you've checked if $digest isn't alreay in progress:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$digest();
// or $apply ..
```

hope this solves your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time AngularJS does not respond is because something is happening outside *the Angular context*, in those cases it's useful to try to replicate the functionality you want with built-in AngularJS directives.

It would be useful to have access to some of the implementation of your component. However, with all the information you have provided, you can use the `ngClick` built-in directive:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn pl-2" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-options"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".create-supplier" ng-click="yourFunctionHere(this)">
      <i class="fa icon-plus text-primary"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      Action
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[AngularJS Docs - ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: Hey, this is not the case - its not that when I am clicking the "Action" it does not get initialized, I talk about the dropdown ul list itself which is not get opened.